# How to force height of container expand according to it's content

Tags: html, css

If we inspect the code,you will see that the `div.header` has `height: 0px;`

Look at image below:

[image]

I want my `div` to be the size of three elements `.c1`,`.c2 and`.c3`

How can I solve this problem?
I hope as well that we managed to explain my problem.

***HTML:***

```
   <div class="container">
    <div class="header">            
        <div class="c1">asdsadsadsadasda</div>
        <div class="c2">asdasdas</div>
        <div class="c3">sadsada</div>            
    </div>
</div>
```

***CSS:***

```css
.container
{
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    background:red;

}
.c1
{
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    background:yellow;
}

.c2
{
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    background:gray;
}


.c3
{
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    background:orange;
}
.c1,.c2,.c3{width:33%;float:left;}

.header{width:70%;height:auto;margin:0 auto;background:blue;}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lq5ruhyt/)

Answer (score 7):

Add `overflow: auto`(*for example*) css property to your `.header` class to recognize it's children's `height`.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lq5ruhyt/1/)

Comment: Thank you, the problem was solved but I used this property?
can you explain a little please?

Comment: @Gigel: this property specifies behavior for element's children in case they are overflowing parent's container size – in other words, here we force element to expand to the size of it's children.

Answer (score 3):

Use clearing divs.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">

        <div class="c1">asdsadsadsadasda</div>
        <div class="c2">asdasdas</div>
        <div class="c3">sadsada</div>
        <div class='clearing'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .clearing {clear:both;}
```